# App crashes when attempting to create tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, crash, android-tabhost

I'm trying to create an activity which contains 4 tabs. The code:

```
public class ManagerActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener {
    private TabHost th;

    private Intent Tab1Intent;
    private Intent Tab2Intent;
    private Intent Tab3Intent;
    private Intent Tab4Intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manager);

        th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        InitTabs(th);
        th.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    private void InitTabs(TabHost th) {
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setIndicator("עדכון הודעות");
        Tab1Intent = new Intent(this, UpdateMessagesActivity.class);
        specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setIndicator("עדכון אירועים");
        Tab2Intent = new Intent(this, UpdateEventsActivity.class);
        specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני השבת");
        Tab3Intent = new Intent(this, updateShabathTimesActivity.class);
        specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני יום חול");
        Tab4Intent = new Intent(this, UpdateDaysTimesActivity.class);
        specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
        th.addTab(specs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tabId.equals("tag1")) {
            startActivity(Tab1Intent);
        } else if (tabId.equals("tag2")) {
            startActivity(Tab1Intent);
        } else if (tabId.equals("tag3")) {
            startActivity(Tab1Intent);
        } else {
            startActivity(Tab1Intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Now, for some reason the app crashes whenever it tries to create the tabs and specs in the InitTabs(th) method call. inside this method, it gets to the first line of adding the tab to the tab host and then it crashes. How should I fix this?

the log:

```
02-14 12:03:14.749: E/Trace(774): error opening trace file: No such file or directory   (2)
02-14 12:03:15.674: D/gralloc_goldfish(774): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-14 12:03:24.273: D/dalvikvm(774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 8% free 2620K/2832K,     paused 38ms, total 51ms
02-14 12:03:24.283: I/dalvikvm-heap(774): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.280MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-14 12:03:24.433: D/dalvikvm(774): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 7% free 3230K/3456K, paused 145ms, total 145ms
02-14 12:03:24.493: D/dalvikvm(774): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3241K/3456K, paused 5ms+21ms, total 63ms
02-14 12:03:24.813: I/Choreographer(774): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-14 12:03:25.613: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(774): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
02-14 12:03:25.613: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(774):   in android.widget.EditText{40de01a8 VFED..CL .F....I. 0,59-456,118 #7f08003b app:id/password}
02-14 12:03:25.613: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(774):   0: sent at 112787000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=112787, downTime=112699, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
02-14 12:03:28.993: D/dalvikvm(774): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 6% free 3541K/3756K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 120ms
02-14 12:03:29.353: D/AndroidRuntime(774): Shutting down VM
02-14 12:03:29.363: W/dalvikvm(774): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.neotavraham/com.example.neotavraham.ManagerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:747)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.example.neotavraham.ManagerActivity.InitTabs(ManagerActivity.java:49)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at com.example.neotavraham.ManagerActivity.onCreate(ManagerActivity.java:38)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-14 12:03:29.444: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  ... 11 more
02-14 12:03:32.503: I/Process(774): Sending signal. PID: 774 SIG: 9
02-14 12:03:34.043: D/gralloc_goldfish(798): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Try setView to set TextView instead of setIndicator. Set icon and indicator text to TextView.

Comment: I added my logcat.. @Anil Bhatiya